# server returns list of tuples to an ajax request but back in the html I need to work on it and html(data) doesn't give a proper structure

Tags: python, django, ajax

I manage to send the ajax request to the server, and the server replies with a list of tuples or it could be a dictionary too, but back in the html that sent the request, this list or dict gets sort of turned into a string and I can't iterate or work on it. This is because of the html(data), but I don't know any other variant other than text(data) but that doesn't solve the problem.
So, once I have sent that list or dict, how can I work on it (like doing iterations) I am using DJANGO.

I simplify the code because this is what matters, suppose I already have a dictionary that I turn into a list:
SERVER (VIEW FUNCTION) RETURNS:

```
dictionary = {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
        lista = list(dictionary.items())
        return HttpResponse(lista)
```

Then back in the html code that sent the request, this results don't keep the nature of the list, but seems like a string

HTML PAGE:

```
...
   ..
    datatype:'html'
                }).done(function(data) {
        $("#received_answer").html(data);
      });  // closing ajax group
                console.log(value);
        }); // closing the click function
    
    });// closing document ready
     </script>
```

I get this: `('key1', 'value1')('key2', 'value2')`

EDITED: I need to tabulate the results, so something like this

```
$("#respuesta").html("<h5>"+data.heating+"</h5>");
```

won't help, because I can't type every single cell and row with double quotes, I would want the Django query set I can loop through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note, dictionary.items() returns tuples, so that may not be the best approach.

You can use an intermediary step like converting to JSON to pass such structures

in your view

```
import json

dictionary = {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
        json_dict = json.dumps(dictionary)
        return HttpResponse(json_dict)
```

and then in your javascript, you'll get a much more javascripty looking string, which your existing code should pick up. You can also parse the string response back into a js object and use that to loop through it.

```
.done(function(data) {
    ///in case we need to debug, we can have a look at what is in data
    console.log(data)
    obj = JSON.parse( data);
    tableHTML = "<table><thead><th>Header1</th><th>Header2</th></thead><tbody>"
    ///iterate through properties with string keys
    
    for (const property in obj) {
      tableHTML += "<tr><td>"
      tableHTML += `${property}</td></td> ${obj[property]}`
      tableHTML += "</td></tr>"
    }
    tableHTML += "</tbody></table>"
    //place the tableHTML in the document
    $("#respuesta").html("tableHTML);
```

Comment: thank you a million times, from your code, where do I place the "obj", I mean I finished here $("#respuesta").html(data); so where should the "obj" go?

Comment: You can build the HTML format in your .done function. I've updated the code to show how you can iterate through the object to build a table.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It has  been great learning because I have gotten to see that when there is an ajax request, the response has to be adapted to that javascript code. I can't return a queryset djangon style, it seems it isn't the kind of object that javascript can accept and also that all of the rest of the code has to be completed within the js body and once done, it is sent to the # in the html page. Obviously I had no understanding of the nature of both entities, what django returns and what js can accept.